# Share defaults between multiple roles in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to share [defaults](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/playbooks_roles.html#role-default-variables) between different roles in Ansible. Is it possible to achieve this directly? Is there a workaround, maybe another approach to this problem? I just want to keep default values DRY.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to put thoses variables in `/etc/ansible/group_vars/all` ?

from [documentation](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/playbooks_variables.html):

> Site wide defaults should be defined as a ‘group_vars/all’ setting.